# Drupal 6 - node/edit in frontend theme

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I have a template for a node/edit form for one of the content types.

This content type will be created/edited by guest users. So I need to get this form displayed in the frontend theme.

How can I set in which theme a form will be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you're looking for the setting that lets you skip using the administration theme for content editing? Just uncheck the box on page `admin/settings/admin` and you're set.

[image: Uncheck the box]

Answer (score 0):

You simply add that template file to whichever folder the theme uses for templates. If you're not using your own custom theme, such as one from core or a contributed one, I recommend creating a subtheme first: https://drupal.org/node/225125